# My car shut off while driving

Tags: nissan

So I was driving down my block when all my light on my car turned on ( oil , brake , battery, ) and right after that my steering wheel got hard and the car turned off but i turned it back on right after . What could it be ?

Comment: What car? And by "all" do you mean every single light available on the dash, or just those 3?

Comment: This sounds like the engine cut out, which would explain all the symptoms. Why it cut out is the question.  It could have been caused by numerous things.  Do you have any history of work done on the car?  Can you add any other information, for example engine temperature ...........?

Comment: I recently changed the engine but they told me every thing was good with the car and I should be good for a good time

Comment: Did anything happen that could have triggered the issue? Did you hit a large bump, turn on something electrical (A/C, headlights, etc)?

Comment: I kinda sidewalk my car while parking . But earlier today I drove on the Parke way for 27 miles . My Mechanic recently added the air coolent.  He told me not to take it on the park way until that was done in waited a week so I could take it on the park way